# android return to fragment from activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I call my activity from my fragment.Inside  the fragment I do this inside `onCreateView`

```
imageViewadd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AjouterNC.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Now from my activity I try to return to the fragment after submit data inside `Asyntask`

```
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    Submit.setEnabled(true);
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    if( getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() != 0 ){
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }
}
```

I tried different ways but I didn't find a solution. Any help would be appreciated?

Comment: thanks for your reply .I look for the way to reload my fragment with finish() the fragment didn't reload

Answer (score 2):

Use this code it might be help you

```
Fragment frag =  new MyFragment();
if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
    }
```

`

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can call fragment from Activity in android.

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
                        .beginTransaction();
     MyFragment fragmentS = new MyFragment();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_content_fragment, fragmentS);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

If you are using `Activity extends FragmentActivity` use `getSupportFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()`

`main_content_fragment` is your container body where you actually place your fragment.
Good Luck!!

Comment: thanks for you reply but i stil have a problem my activity extends from AppCompatActivity and the my fragment extends from Fragment i use this code   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
                    .beginTransaction();
            PNCFragment fragmentS = new PNCFragment();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragmentS);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your fragment to the backstack. When you create a new activity your fragment gets removed and must be added again. The solution is to keep the code of adding the fragment in the **onStart()** of the activity.

For example you've fragment F in Activity A. When the click event occurs in the fragment F you start the activity named **AjouterNC**. The fragment F is removed from the activity, **onStop()** of Activity A is called and Activity A is added to the backstack. When you press backpress in **AjouterNC**, Activity A comes back to the top and **onStart()** is called. In **onStart()** method keep the code for adding or replacing the fragment.